# ASP.NET MVC Razor SQL tabel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm noobie in this, but I'm learning.

This is an database SQL question. This was really easy in classic ASP.

I have 2 tables in my database. Books and genre.

In my show books page, you'll get from db:

```
| Book name | book Author | book genre |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| eden      | paulo       | 1          |
| mystic    | paulo       | 2          |
```

The genre is

```
| id  | book genre |
+-----+------------+
| 1   | action     |
| 2   | horror     |
```

What I like is

```
| Book name | book Author | book genre |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| eden      | paulo       | action     |
| mystic    | paulo       | horror     |
```

As I said earlier this was super easy in classic asp.

How can I do this in ASP.NET MVC with Razor?

Comment: It's super easy in ASP.NET MVC with Razor too. Which part are you struggling with? Did you write a query to obtain the data you want? Define classes to represent your data? Execute your query to create instances of the classes? Pass that model to your view? Try iterating over the model within the view to create the HTML markup? Which specific part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

If your Book and Genre table are already connected with the Foreign key then you can fetch the data like this.

Create a view model:

```
public class BookList{
  public string Name  {get;set;}
public string Author {get;set;}
public string Genre {get;set;}
}

var books  = _context.Books.Include(x=>x.Genre).Select(x=> new BookList(){
  Name = x.BookNmae,
  Auther = x.BookAuthor,
  Genre = x.Genre.BookGenre
}).ToList()
```

Send this model to a view :

and in view you just need to loop through the model to create table rows.

```
<table>
<thead> <th>Book Name</th><th>Book Author</th><th>Book Genre</th></thead>
<tbody>
@foreach(var m in Model){
 <tr><td>@m.Name</td><td>@m.Author</td><td>@m.Genre</td></tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```